# jquery animation changing z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, z-index

I was making a page where the five green circles should 'bounce' once upon entering them, and then something should appear underneath. Please see [this  JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/R5a79/).

I encountered an issue where if I just used the ".button" class, the animation would bounce uncontrollably as the cursor moved over the div.
I have attempted to solve that by overlaying a separate ".sbutton" div with a z-index which keeps it on top, so it should be independent of the bouncing ".button" class. It has been given a colour (red) so the z-index can be examined in the jsfiddle example.

Here's the JS portion:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var selector;

$( ".sbutton" ).mouseenter(function(){
    selector = "#" + 1 + $( this ).attr('id');
    $(selector).effect("bounce", { times:1 }, 120);
});

$( ".sbutton" ).mouseover(function(){
    selector = "#" + 1 + $( this ).attr('id');
    $( "#menudisplay" ).html("<p>" + selector + "</p>");

    $( ".sbutton" ).mouseleave(function(){
        $( "#menudisplay" ).html("");
    });

});

});
```

**My question is:** Why does the ".sbutton" div not stay on top of the ".button" div, even when the z-indexes are specified?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you explicitly set `position: relative` the `z-index` will work. The reason is:

> Although z-index is not a difficult property to understand, due to
>   false assumptions it can cause confusion for beginning developers.
>   This confusion occurs because z-index will only work on an element
>   whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or
>   relative.

As explained at the site below:

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7Ztap/

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck for ages trying to figure it out.